# Is there a Post Office in Heathrow?

Tags: uk, lhr, mail

I am flying from India to England on Saturday and will reach Heathrow on Sunday morning. I would like to post a gift to my friend from Heathrow Airport. Is that possible?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38456/can-i-collect-post-at-near-heathrow-airport-on-a-saturday

Answer (score 9):

There is a Post Office branch in Heathrow Terminal 3.

Photo at https://flic.kr/p/iZidNM

It is open every day but only 5 hours on Sundays, from 9 AM to 1 PM.  Walking directions are [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/51.471289,-0.452386/51.46971,-0.45184/@51.4707277,-0.45526,17z/data=!3m1!4b1)

Comment: They only open once a week?

Comment: LOL, no, normal hours on business days, but the OP is focused on Sunday, which has limited hours :)  Edited for clarity

Answer (score 7):

At Heathrow the post office is located in terminal 3

http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/services-and-facilities/postal-services

There are post boxes located in all terminals both before and after security.  Anything posted can be inspected by HMRC.

Also the postboxes at Heathrow are size limited so only letters can be posted.

Below is a screen grab from the post office website.   It details the opening times.  Current as of 24/May/2015

[image]

Also you can purchace books of postage stamps at branches of WHSmith located in all terminals