# Post office for parcels at Heathrow Terminal 5

Tags: lhr, shopping, mail

I am arriving on a flight into London Heathrow Terminal 5, and leaving a few hours later on a flight from the same terminal. My luggage will not be checked through (different tickets). I want to post a largish parcel ideally from Terminal 5 to a UK address.

I know there is/was a post office at T5 [in WH Smith](https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/terminal-facilities/postal-services) (also [here](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/branch-finder/0210250/heathrow-airport-terminal-5)). But [this site](https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/shops-a-z/post-office) says the Post Office only exists at T3 and is "temporarily closed for Covid". [This site](https://www.royalmail.com/services-near-you/post-office/heathrow-airport-terminal-5-tw6-2ga) suggests there is a T5 Post Office, and with no mention of it being in WH Smith. And there are other [questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48073/is-there-a-post-office-in-heathrow) on this site relating to a post office in 2015 (not useful now). So, in June 2023, is there a Post Office in LHR T5, and does it take parcels? Even better, does it sell protective stuff to wrap a parcel in?

Comment: I'm not in a position to verify it myself, but [this article](https://www.betterretailing.com/retail-services/post-office-branch-opens-at-heathrow-airports-terminal-5/) suggests that the T3 and T5 post offices are both in landside WHSmith stores and reopened in December 2021.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is indeed a post office in Heathrow Terminal 5 in June 2023. It's located in the WH Smith on the departures floor (Floor 3), at the South end (next to South Security). It takes parcels, and has some limited parcel packaging for sale (a little challenging if your parcel is large).
[image: WH Smiths / Post Office at T5]
(photo: me)

Comment: Is this your photo?  If not, you should credit the source.

Comment: It's my photo. I will add something to that effect. @PeterM